# How to combine line plot and Box Plot with significant differences in same graph in R

Tags: r, plot

I am looking for a chart where I can draw to combine a line graph chart with Box plot and significantly different with tukey letters in the same graph in R.

I am trying to figure 2 of the following manuscript
"Coordination of intra and inter-species leaf traits according to leaf
phenology and plant age for three temperate broadleaf species with different
shade tolerances"

[image]

Here is my data structure

```
Stage   Species PAM
Young   RA  2.6051
Young   RA  2.7351
Young   RA  3.5751
Young   RA  2.7851
Young   RA  2.8451
Young   RA  2.8351
Young   RA  2.8851
Young   RA  3.2051
Young   RA  2.6951
Young   RA  3.4051
Young   RA  3.1251
Young   RA  3.4751
Young   RA  2.5551
Young   RA  1.9951
Young   RA  1.8651
Young   RA  2.1451
Young   RA  1.8151
Mature  RA  7.6051
Mature  RA  6.7351
Mature  RA  5.5751
Mature  RA  4.7851
Mature  RA  5.8451
Mature  RA  4.8351
Mature  RA  4.8851
Mature  RA  4.2051
Mature  RA  6.6951
Mature  RA  4.4051
Mature  RA  4.1251
Mature  RA  3.5751
Mature  RA  3.3551
Mature  RA  2.9951
Mature  RA  2.8651
Mature  RA  3.1451
Mature  RA  2.8151
Old RA  2.4651
Old RA  2.1051
Old RA  3.0351
Old RA  1.8951
Old RA  1.9251
Old RA  2.5451
Old RA  2.4951
Old RA  2.2751
Old RA  2.3051
Old RA  2.8151
Old RA  3.1251
Old RA  3.4751
Old RA  2.5551
Old RA  1.9951
Old RA  1.8651
Old RA  2.1451
Old RA  1.8151
Young   QL  8.4214
Young   QL  8.2114
Young   QL  7.8914
Young   QL  8.0514
Young   QL  8.0914
Young   QL  7.8414
Young   QL  7.2814
Young   QL  7.6814
Young   QL  7.0314
Young   QL  2.3814
Young   QL  2.5114
Young   QL  3.3514
Young   QL  2.5614
Young   QL  2.6214
Young   QL  2.6114
Young   QL  2.6614
Young   QL  2.9814
Mature  QL  9.4214
Mature  QL  11.2114
Mature  QL  10.8914
Mature  QL  9.0514
Mature  QL  10.0914
Mature  QL  10.8414
Mature  QL  9.2814
Mature  QL  10.6814
Mature  QL  9.0314
Mature  QL  7.3814
Mature  QL  6.5114
Mature  QL  5.3514
Mature  QL  4.5614
Mature  QL  5.6214
Mature  QL  4.6114
Mature  QL  4.6614
Mature  QL  3.9814
Old QL  5.9914
Old QL  6.7914
Old QL  5.4714
Old QL  5.6214
Old QL  6.6614
Old QL  5.6914
Old QL  4.7414
Old QL  5.6314
Old QL  5.6014
Old QL  2.2414
Old QL  1.8814
Old QL  2.8114
Old QL  1.6714
Old QL  1.7014
Old QL  2.3214
Old QL  2.2714
Old QL  2.0514
```

Comment: What is your question